# Overriding model factory defaults with a dynamically computed property

Tags: php, laravel

Disclaimer: Almost zero experience with PHP.

Using ‘tinker’… I have created (and persistent) two user models with ids 1,2 respectively. Now, I want to create a number of posts (Post model) and I want to override the default attributes such that it will be a random number between 1 and 2 (as per the user ids).

How can I achieve this? I can’t really pass to the overrides array something like

```
[‘user_id’ => rand( 1, 2 )]
```

as this will only be computed once and thus, all posts will have the same user. Also, i don't want to override the attribute within the ModelFactory.php as i want the user_id range to be dynamically computed.

Thanks in advance.

SK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this passing the 'user_id' in the method ->create();

```
factory(App\Post::class, 2)->create(['user_id' => rand(1, 2)]);
```

Hope it helps